# setting namespace true while parsing in dom4j

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces, dom4j

I am parsing one xml document using dom4j as below

```
            SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
    document = reader.read("C:/test.xml");
```

But it does not keep the namespaces that were there when i write the xml as below

```
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:/test.xml");

    OutputFormat format = OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint();

    XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter(fos, format);


    writer.write(document);

    writer.flush();
```

how to do this using dom4j.I am using dom4j because of code easiness.

Answer (score 0):

Don't agree. This snippet

```
    System.out.println(new SAXReader()
            .read(new ByteArrayInputStream("<a:c xmlns:a='foo'/>"
                    .getBytes(Charset.forName("utf-8")))).getRootElement()
            .getNamespaceURI());
```

will print

`foo`

Your problem is that the `SAXReader#read(String)` method takes a `System ID`argument, not a file name. Instead, try feeding the reader a `File`, or an `InputStream`, or a `URL`.

```
 reader.read(new File("C:/test.xml"))
```